# Firefox Popup window event

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

I am writing a Firefox extension using XPCOM C++.

I want to get notified when the popup window (like we see while browsing www.rediffmail.com) is opening.

How do I catch this event?
Does anybody knows how to do it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: cross-referencing duplicate post: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1705505

Answer (score 1):

"like we see while browsing www.rediffmail.com" is a poor definition, so I'm going to assume you're talking about regular popup windows (with title bar, etc), not a Javascript-implemented in-tab dialog, and not new pages that open in new tabs.

There are [notifications fired when new windows are open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Windows) (or you could just overlay Firefox's browser.xul to inject your code).

There's also a [PopupWindow DOM event](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.cpp#5005), not documented, as far as I can see.